# How to test if two numbers are close in Clojure

Tags: unit-testing, testing, clojure

What is the idiomatic way to test if two numbers are close to each other in Clojure?

Somewhere along the line of:

```
(deftest sqrt-test
   (is (~= 1.414 (Math/sqrt 2)))
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'll need to define "close". If you ask for a "difference" of less than some tolerance, you can roll your own function using `<`:

```
(defn close? [tolerance x y]
  (< (difference x y) tolerance))
```

Where difference might be absolute:

```
(defn absolute-difference ^double [^double x ^double y]
  (Math/abs (double (- x y))))
```

or relative:

```
(defn relative-difference ^double [^double x ^double y]
  (/ (Math/abs (- x y))
     (max (Math/abs x) (Math/abs y))))
```

(pick your preferred definition of relative difference, of course).

Then `(partial close? 0.001)` will test approximate equality with tolerance of 0.001.

To discover limits on useful values of the tolerance parameter you can use `Math/ulp`, which is a static method which takes a double and returns the absolute difference between it and the smallest larger double.

Answer (score 5):

Although I like the solution of Michał Marczyk, note that there already is

approx=

function defined in clojure.algo.generic.math-functions. Sample usage:

```
clojuree.o=> (approx= 1.41 (sqrt 2) 1e-2)
true
clojuree.o=> (approx= 1.41 (sqrt 2) 1e-4)
false
```